# Why is my object not displaying in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

This should be a relatively simple problem, but it is driving me insane.  I am trying to create Mine Sweeper in JavaFX (mostly just for practice) but I can not get even a simple rectangle to display.  I had the game running once before, but I am trying to make the game more abstract, and hence easier to code, but I am running into the issue of nothing being displayed.

I eliminated all extraneous code so it is as simple as possible.  I am basically trying to create a Rectangle with a certain color and size called Box, add the box to the pane, and display the pane.  In order to make Box a node that can be displayed on the pane, I made the Box class extend Rectangle, so that a Box would have the same properties as a Rectangle.  But when I run the code, it gives just an empty pane with no box in it.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Minesweeper extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        Pane pane = new Pane();

        Box box = new Box();

        pane.getChildren().addAll(box);     

        // Create the scene
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        stage.setTitle("Minesweeper");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}

import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

public class Box extends Rectangle {

    public Box() {

        Rectangle box = new Rectangle(100, 100, 100, 100);

        box.setFill(Color.BLUE);

    }

}
```

I realized if I put the code from Box into the main Minesweeper class, it will display the box.  But Box will have a ton of other properties and therefore needs to be a class on its own.

What am I doing wrong that does not allow the box to be displayed?

Thanks in advance for your help and consideration.

Comment: You're creating a new Rectangle object in the Box constructor, but not storing it anywhere or doing anything with it. Is there some `paint` method you should override?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a new `Rectangle` in your `Box` class. This `Rectangle` is not added to any `Parent` container, so it's not visible. 
Change your code to:

```
    public Box() {
        super(100, 100, 100, 100);
        setFill(Color.BLUE);
    }
```

Comment: That's perfect.  Thank you very much.  Makes perfect sense too.